# How to "simulate" or emulate if-then-else or case-statement in Terraform

Tags: if-statement, terraform, conditional-statements, case-statement

I am looking for a way to do this in Terraform, if possible.
Assume that ami and region are variables in the variable.tf file.
(in pseudo-code)

```
If region = "us-east-1" then
  ami = "123455679"
else if region = "us-west-1" then
  ami = "98765432"
endif
```

I know there is no "if-then-else" or case-statements in Terraform but seems like there should be a way to do this.

Is it possible?  Can you point me to an example or article?

TIA
Bill W

Comment: Hi Bill, please let me know if my answer helped you by accepting it or please ask any follow up questions you may have

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Conditional Expressions](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html) are what you are looking for

You can set the ami variable like this

```
ami = (region == "us-east-1" ? "123455679" : "98765432")
```

If you have more than 2 regions you can keep adding conditionals, although that may be hard to read. In that case you could use a [map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/map.html) variable type (aka a dictionary).

```
ami = ({
  "us-east-1" = "123455679"
  "us-west-1" = "98765432"
})
```